# NHibernate spatial geometry type become NULL

Tags: postgis, c#, mapping, hibernate-spatial

I am using postgres/postgis as db and Nhibernate as ORM on a C# project.

This is the first time I try to map postgis to a .Net application. My setup uses NHibernate version 4.0.4.4000 and NHibernate.Spatial.PostGis 4.0.4.4000 (with Npgsql version 3.0.5)

I followed [this tutorial](http://nhibernate.info/doc/spatial/configuration-and-mapping.html) in order to set up the mappings, so I have:

in the web.config

```
<property name="dialect">NHibernate.Spatial.Dialect.PostGisDialect,NHibernate.Spatial.PostGis</property>
```

for the nhibernate configuration I added

```
cfg.AddAuxiliaryDatabaseObject(new SpatialAuxiliaryDatabaseObject(cfg));
```

my xml mapping file has the following mapping:

```
<property name="Geom" column="the_geom" type="NHibernate.Spatial.Type.GeometryType, NHibernate.Spatial" />
```

and my model class has the following property

```
public virtual IGeometry Geom { get; set; }
```

Now when ever I fetch any of the geometries the property Geom is null.
In the logs I don't get exceptions nor error messages. 
I don't know what else to try.

In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29163236/mapping-geometry-from-sqlserver2008-to-net-nhibernate-4-0-0-4000), using MS sql server, he got it working because he figured out that hist current dll (Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.dll) and the required one supported different versions of Ms sql, so mapping that dll to an older version fixed the problem. Could that be the case here? how/what can I try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The is a known problem of NHibernate with Npgsql 3. Npgsql 3 change the way it return value of geometry. Switch to Npgsql 2.2.7 and everything will just work.

Comment: Great, that did the trick, thank you. Could you point me to where this issue is reported? I would like to track it to know when it has been fixed.

Comment: This issue is not report to NHibernate bug tracker yet. I found this issue by myself when try to upgrade Npgsql. You should report this issue because i'm not strong at english language.

Answer (score 1):

The [Hibernate Page](http://nhibernate.info/doc/spatial/configuration-and-mapping.html) page has some fine print that may point to your issues.

> NOTE: Type parameters (see NHibernate mapping above) are not supported
>   in ActiveRecord.

...

> NHibernate Mapping:

```
In the XML mappings file, map all properties as usual but for geometry
columns use the following entry: <property name="Geometry"
column="the_geom" type="NHibernate.Spatial.Type.GeometryType,
NHibernate.Spatial" />
```

It almost sounds like they are running you around in circles, if you are using ActiveRecord.  You may have to look for some other examples to find the correct "handshake" to make this work.  It is times like this that makes me feel like these ORM tools are more work than if I just used the database directly.

Comment: Hi Greg. As far as I know, I am not using ActiveRecord with nHibernate, I am using xml mappings (hbm files). Any other thoughts?